# Why do we sweat on a hot and humid day but the clothes are able to dry?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, biology, evaporation, humidity

I know that on a humid day,water vapour content is high in air and as a result evaporation of sweat is lesser and hence we feel hotter. What I am not able to get is, if water vapour content is high,how are clothes able to dry faster on humid days. Should'nt it take time for the moisture in them to evaporate?

Comment: Where does the claim that "clothes dry faster on humid days" come from ? Is it documented ? I'm not saying it has to be wrong, but just that it is far to be an obvious observation for me (maybe it's on me). Please also consider that the drying kinetics are quite complex, and that other factors can impact the speed (temperature, air circulation...). That may bias your observations if your claim is mostly based on a "it seems to me that..."

Comment: It's just my observation as summers are naturally more humid because of high temperature and clothes dry faster here in summers.

Comment: Are you sure that your summers are more humid? You should measure it. Personally, I see all summers hotter and drier, except for us and our sweat, but the environment is dryer.

Comment: Man I wish this was the case for me

Comment: @FGSUZ I have considered sweatiness as the measure.I will proceed by measuring.

Comment: When Summers are more humid, are you then also taking into account the higher temperatures? A humid air slows down the drying of clothes, but the higher temperature speeds it up. What exactly are the conditions under which you observe that "*clothes [are] able to dry faster on humid days*"

Comment: @Steeven The only index I have chosen is humidity for the reason I already mentioned that hot air is more humid.

Comment: But that is not correct. Hot air is not necessarily more humid. Humidity is no related to temperature in general. I can easily heat a pressure container full of air so it becomes more hot without having any humidity added or removed. Take a trip to Vietnam with high humidity due to their rainfalls and closeness to open water, and then go to Death Valley in the USA, the hottest place on Earth, that is immensely dry since it is so far from water sources. Try to hang your clothes to dry in either place and you'll see a difference. Humidity and temperature are in general two unrelated parameters.

Comment: You're almost definitely conflating humidity and heat. Does "here" refer to somewhere on the Indian West Coast, e.g. Bombay? Because it's pretty common "here" to claim that summers "here" are humid when they're actually savannah-level dry.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am not able to get is, if water vapour content is high,how are
>   clothes able to dry faster on humid days

They don't. They definitely dry faster on less humid days, *assuming the temperature is the same in both cases*. If you put clothes out in the Altiplano they dry real fast, which is great at the end of the day and hang up your cycling jersey and its dry before you get your socks off.